# Java: embeddable Object-Oriented-Database

Tags: java, embeddable, object-oriented-database

I am looking for simple-to-use embeddable Open-source Object-oriented database for Java desktop application.

I am working on small portable Java app with embedded database. Originally I was thinking of using SQLite or H2 with JPA. However I am not the 100% sure that the data scheme will not change over time and I am already working with Objects so I might save some trouble by using ODBMS right away.

Maven repository and GUI would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html

As GUI you can use: http://www.dbvis.com/

Comment: Berkeley will do just fine. I was hoping to find something like db4o (witch seems kinda... dead).

Comment: If you are looking for a non-relational db take a look to leveldb. It is pretty popular and used in major projects like Akka and Apache Apollo. Note there are native and java implementations of levelb.